# KeyError: 'opsworkscm' when attempting to use the AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

When attempting to use the AWS CLI for the EC2 instance I'm working with, I receive the following error.

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~]$ aws

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 27, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/aws", line 23, in main
    return awscli.clidriver.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 54, in main
return driver.main()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 186, in main
command_table = self._get_command_table()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 96, in _get_command_table
    self._command_table = self._build_command_table()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 116, in _build_command_table
command_object=self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore-1.4.8-py2.7.egg/botocore/session.py", line 680, in emit
return self._events.emit(event_name, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore-1.4.8-py2.7.egg/botocore/hooks.py", line 226, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore-1.4.8-py2.7.egg/botocore/hooks.py", line 209, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/customizations/opsworkscm.py", line 21, in alias_opsworks_cm
alias_command(command_table, 'opsworkscm', 'opsworks-cm')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/customizations/utils.py", line 71, in alias_command
current = command_table[existing_name]
KeyError: 'opsworkscm'
```

I am not quite sure why this is happening. I am working with other ec2 instances setup similar to this one that work, but I am not sure what difference may be causing this error.

Comment: What happens if you type ``aws --version``?

Comment: @garnaat I get the same error shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran across this issue in the aws-cli GH repo.  I ran `sudo pip install awscli` and it updated botocore to version 1.4.86 which fixed my issue.

[Issue in aws-cli GH repo](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/2310)

Answer (score 0):

I was using Ubuntu Xenial and needed to have awscli newer than 1.4.38 so I was using awscli from Ubuntu / Zesty.

As with pip, you need to upgrade python3-botocore so this worked for me:

```
apt-get install awscli python3-botocore
```

(from zesty repository).

Answer (score 0):

Your `/usr/bin/aws` must be an old executable.

- Run `whereis aws`. You will get a **list** of `aws` executables.
- Find the most recent one by running `aws --version`.
- Remove the corrupted executable. In your case `sudo rm /usr/bin/aws`